# Build failed: Quota exceeded for quota metric after upgrade Node 14 to 16

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I upgrade Node Engine 14 to 16 in package.json. Now I cannot deploy all cloud functions once.

I run this command to deploy all functions once.

```json
"deploy-dev": "firebase use dev && firebase deploy --only functions"
```

**Error Message on terminal**

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        chatFieldDisableOnce(us-central1)
        chatFieldReqUpdateOnce(us-central1)
        contactYello(us-central1)
        createPayment(us-central1)
        makePayment(us-central1)
        paymentCapture(us-central1)
        reviewUpdateOnce(us-central1)
        sendPostPromotion(us-central1)
        vendorCountToSub(us-central1)
```

**I check the log. I found this error**

```
{
"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
"status": {
   "code":8,
   "message":"Build failed: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Build Create requests' and limit 'Build Create requests per minute' of service 'cloudbuild.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:number is here'."
},
"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"xxx@gmail.com"},
"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
"methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
"resourceName":"projects/yellochat-12b69/locations/us-central1/functions/sendPostPromotion"
}
```

I currently deploy all failure functions one by one using this command. This one is working fine.

```json
firebase use dev && firebase deploy --only functions:function_name
```

Comment: How many functions do you deploy in the same time?

Comment: 25 functions. It's run without any issues when running on nodeJS 14.

Comment: When you deploy all the 25 function in nodejs 14 it works, right? not in nodejs16? Strange.... Because you have Cloud Build quotas that limit the number of Cloud Build in the same time, node 14 or 16 have the same deployment mode and use Cloud Build in a similar fashion.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Now I tried again after restart the lap same command using node 16. Now it's working fine without any issues. `npm run deploy-dev`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions), if your project contains more than 5 functions then it is recommended to mention specific function names using --only to avoid running into deployment quotas limits.

Example: firebase deploy --only functions:addMessage,functions:makeUppercase